# Read images from url and put them on a dataframe column with the label to another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, image

I would like to read images from url and place them on a pandas dataframe column and place label to another another column. How can I do that please help. Below is the dataframe from the file I read. There 4 url pages with the 4 labeled.But I have to exclude .svg images from it since it does not display any pictures.
So final outcome will be on
df={'image':....,'label':['icon','icon','icon']}
Thank you

```
import pandas as pd

data={'image_url':['https://www.philips.com/c-dam/b2c/en_US/experience/sound-and- 
vision/headphones/fidelio-l3/L3_38_hr_88x88.png'
,'https://www.philips.com/c-dam/b2c/tv/categorypage/us/AndroidTVLP/HDR.png'
,'https://www.philips.com/c-dam/b2c/category-pages/sound-and- 
vision/headphones/master/homepage/awaraness-mode-anc.png'],
,'https://https://www.philips.com/c-dam/b2c/master/experience/pe/shavers/360-d.svg'
'label':['icon','icon','icon','icon']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

#Below is what I tried so far with no success 
img=[]
image=df['image_url']
for i in image:
if not i.endswith('.svg'):
response = requests.get(i)
img1 = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img.extend(img1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
img = []
image = df['image_url']
for i in image:
    if not i.endswith('.svg'):
        response = requests.get(i)
        img1 = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        img.extend([img1])
    else:
        img.extend([None])
df['image'] = pd.DataFrame(img)
```